# What tools do you use to clean corrupt data?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

Customer often send currupt data for analysis. I spent a lot of time in cleaning the data or waiting for a correct dataset.
Can you recommend a tool that can handle the most common curruptions (eg. wrong set quotes)...

Comment: http://openrefine.org/ and https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/ For manual cleaning: Spark and pandas, for big and small data, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka has built in preprocessing techniques 
Also u may need to check the powerful tool named dataPreparator as it provides a variety of techniques for data cleaning, transformation, and exploration
Chaining of preprocessing operators into a flow graph (operator tree) and it can
Handle large volumes of data (since data sets are not stored in the computer memory) through a user friendly graphical user interface

Answer (score 0):

If you know the nature of data you require as suggested by @Emre for manual cleaning you can use Apache Spark or Pandas. Utilizing the data frame aspects of both Spark and Pandas will help you preprocess data with a much easier convenience. Because data frames account for any data type it's easy to access and clean specifically the segments you require. If the corrupt data is of repetitive nature you can use several Map reduce techniques to clean it fast as well. If it's the case of big data.